# why does my "dp" function have strange parameter? and it seems to cause segmentation error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am solving a problem on Kattis, which is [course planning](https://open.kattis.com/problems/courseplanning). However, there is a problem that I don't know how to solve. I use VS Code on a Windows 10 computer to write this code, but this problem didn't occur before when I was trying to solve the problem. I'm a beginner, so it would be quite easy for you guys.

```
void dp(int l, int r, int minnum, int maxnum, int posnum){
    cout << l << " " << r << "\n";
    int this_size = r - l + 1;
    if(posnum == 0){
        //edge
        if (this_size == 1){
            if(minnum == 0)dpl[minnum] = 0;
            if(maxnum == 1)dpl[maxnum] = course[r].val;
            return;
        }
        if (this_size == 2){
            if(minnum == 0)dpl[minnum] = 0;
            if(minnum <= 1 && maxnum >= 1)dpl[minnum + 1] = min(course[l].val, course[r].val);
            if(maxnum == 2)dpl[maxnum] = course[l].val + course[r].val;
            return;
        }

        int ll = l, lr = (l + r) >> 1, rl = ((l + r) >> 1) + 1, rr = r;
        int ans[maxn], ansl[maxn], ansr[maxn];
        //trans correct
        if(course[lr].type == 1 && course[rl].type == 2){
            if(rl + 1 <= rr)lr++, rl++;
            else if(lr - 1 >= l)lr-- , rl--;
        }
        int lsize = lr - ll + 1, rsize = rr - rl + 1;
        int lmin = (minnum - rsize > z)?(minnum - rsize):(0), lmax = (lsize > maxnum)?(maxnum):(lsize);
        int rmin = (minnum - lsize > z)?(minnum - lsize):(0), rmax = (rsize > maxnum)?(maxnum):(rsize);

        //trans
        dp(ll, lr, lmin, lmax, 0);
        copy(dpl + lmin, dpl + lmax + 1, ansl + lmin);
        dp(rl, rr, rmin, rmax, 1);
        copy(dpr + rmin, dpr + rmax + 1, ansr + rmin);

        for(int i = minnum; i <= maxnum; i++){
            int lptr = lmin, rptr = rmax;
            if(lptr + rptr > i)rptr -= lptr + rptr - i;
            if(lptr + rptr < i)lptr += i - (lptr + rptr);

            int cmpnum = ansl[lptr] + ansr[rptr];
            while(lptr <= lmax && rptr >= rmin){
                cmpnum = min(cmpnum, ans[lptr] + ansr[rptr]);
                lptr++, rptr--;
            }
            ans[i] = cmpnum;
        }
        copy(ans + minnum, ans + maxnum + 1, dpl + minnum);
    }
    else if(posnum == 1){   //remember to update this part
        //edge
        if (this_size == 1){
            if(minnum == 0)dpr[minnum] = 0;
            if(maxnum == 1)dpr[maxnum] = course[r].val;
            return;
        }
        if (this_size == 2){
            if(minnum == 0)dpr[minnum] = 0;
            if(minnum <= 1 && maxnum >= 1)dpr[minnum + 1] = min(course[l].val, course[r].val);
            if(maxnum == 2)dpr[maxnum] = course[l].val + course[r].val;
            return;
        }

        int ll = l, lr = (l + r) >> 1, rl = ((l + r) >> 1) + 1, rr = r;
        int ans[maxn], ansl[maxn], ansr[maxn];
        //trans correct
        if(course[lr].type == 1 && course[rl].type == 2){
            if(rl + 1 <= rr)lr++, rl++;
            else if(lr - 1 >= l)lr-- , rl--;
        }
        int lsize = lr - ll + 1, rsize = rr - rl + 1;
        int lmin = (minnum - rsize > z)?(minnum - rsize):(0), lmax = (lsize > maxnum)?(maxnum):(lsize);
        int rmin = (minnum - lsize > z)?(minnum - lsize):(0), rmax = (rsize > maxnum)?(maxnum):(rsize);

        //trans
        dp(ll, lr, lmin, lmax, 0);
        copy(dpl + lmin, dpl + lmax + 1, ansl + lmin);
        dp(rl, rr, rmin, rmax, 1);
        copy(dpr + rmin, dpr + rmax + 1, ansr + rmin);

        for(int i = minnum; i <= maxnum; i++){
            int lptr = lmin, rptr = rmax;
            if(lptr + rptr > i)rptr -= lptr + rptr - i;
            if(lptr + rptr < i)lptr += i - (lptr + rptr);

            int cmpnum = ansl[lptr] + ansr[rptr];
            while(lptr <= lmax && rptr >= rmin){
                cmpnum = min(cmpnum, ans[lptr] + ansr[rptr]);
                lptr++, rptr--;
            }
            ans[i] = cmpnum;
        }
        copy(ans + minnum, ans + maxnum + 1, dpr + minnum);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: First, this `int ans[maxn], ansl[maxn], ansr[maxn];` is not valid C++.  Dynamic arrays in C++ are done by using `std::vector`.  Second, [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: tks! i'll correct that problem.